# Fetching parent and child nodes along with counts

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using the nested model according to a [guide from this article](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/).

> The nested category table is as follows.

[image: nested_category]

> The product table is as follows.

[image: product]

I want to get the parent node & the child nodes of a selected level. Eg: If television was selected the query should display. Additionally the count of each products in each category should also be displayed.

```
Electronics
  Television
    Tube     (2)
    LCD      (1)
    Plasma   (2)
```

I wrote the following query

```
SELECT parent.name, count(product.product_id)
FROM nested_category AS node,nested_category AS parent,nested_category AS midpoint
LEFT JOIN product ON product.product_id=midpoint.category_id
WHERE (node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt) AND (node.lft BETWEEN midpoint.lft AND midpoint.rgt) AND midpoint.name='TELEVISIONS'
GROUP BY parent.name
ORDER BY node.lft
```

The result I get is here

[image: Results from my query]

This gets all the children & parent node properly but the count is wrong. [Check the SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d99d3/4)

Comment: How is it wrong? You're doing an `OUTER JOIN`. Do you want `NULL`s to be counted?

Comment: Its a LEFT JOIN. I want the NULLs to be shown as 0..

Comment: I edited the question slightly..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT parent.category_id as pid, parent.name as pname, SUM(product.product_id IS NOT NULL)
FROM
nested_category AS parent,
nested_category AS midpoint,
nested_category AS node
LEFT JOIN product ON product.category_id=node.category_id
WHERE (node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt)
AND (node.lft BETWEEN midpoint.lft AND midpoint.rgt)
AND midpoint.name='TELEVISIONS'
GROUP BY parent.category_id
ORDER BY parent.category_id;
```

Comment: This still gives Televisions count as 4 where in fact there are 5 televisions in the database.

Comment: yup, the original query was borked. Check it now. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d99d3/13

Comment: Thanks this is working correctly. I declared the alias midpoint to get parent categories and child categories of a selected element. I am not 100% confident on that. Do you think its the way to achieve this.

Comment: Honestly, I never saw it done like that till now. I guess it will work if you can guarantee that your category ids will be assigned the right way. But you might get a lot of headache if e.g. later you would need to insert extra category ids somewhere in the beginning...